# Can you complete messages from a Service Bus Queue based on a condition with .NET?

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I currently have a Service Bus Queue that receives a message via HTTP Trigger, and has the messages extracted via a Service Bus Trigger. The Service Bus Triger message is sent to a Web Application to have Envelopes processed. I wanted to know if there was a way to prevent the messages inside of the service bus queue from being completed until I get a response back from the web application that indicated success. I have an idea as to how I would deliver the response back to the service bus trigger after processing, I just need to know if I can complete the message then.

As of right now, I have configured the autoCompleteMeessages setting in the host.json file to false, but it doesn't seem to halt the process at all.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions" : {
    "serviceBus": {
      "autoCompleteMessages": false,
      "transportType": "amqpWebSockets",
      "webProxy": "mwgproxy"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Function App configuration? Autocomplete distinguishes whether the dequeued message will be immediately completed by the trigger, it doesn't change the rate at which the trigger is invoked. If you don't complete the message and abandon it, it will reappear on the queue after its lock duration expires. This is by design.

Comment: You may be seeing an abundance of messages if you are successfully processing them but not calling the complete operation on a MessageReceiver, because no completion is indicating that the message has failed to be processed and should be requeued, which will cause it to trigger again.

Comment: You are correct, this is for a Function App configuration. I understand the trigger will be invoked regardless, all I wanted was to delay the message completion process depending on if a certain action was successful. Luckily, I was able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed how to do it using ServiceBusReceivedMessage and ServiceBusMessageActions inside of my argument body inside of visual studio. Link for reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus#message-settlement

```
[FunctionName("ReadMessageFromQ")]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("thequeue")]ServiceBusReceivedMessage myQueueItem, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, ILogger log)
        {


            string payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myQueueItem.Body);

            EnvelopePayload envelopeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnvelopePayload>(payload);



            bool response = true;


            if (response) 
            {
                await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(myQueueItem);
                
                log.LogInformation($"Processed Sequence Number: {myQueueItem.SequenceNumber}");
                log.LogInformation($"Processed MessageId: {myQueueItem.MessageId}");
            }
            else
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Sequence Number: {myQueueItem.SequenceNumber} was not able to be processed. Will be placed in the Dead-Letter Queue.");
                await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(myQueueItem);
            }


        }
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach. If the response was not received because of some intermittent failure, you'd dead-letter the message w/o a single retry attempt.

Comment: Could you point me to documentation where I can retry sending a message that has been put inside the DLQ?

Comment: I don't know if that documentation exists. The guidance is to usually let the message be retried until it's moved to the DLQ by Functions.